# postgresql what means max connections?

Tags: postgresql

What does "max connections" mean in PostgreSQL?

Maybe I have `max_connections = 500`, and 1000 users come to my site then for the other 500 is the database not available? Or did I misunderstand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `max_connections` to 500 then the database will accept at most 500 connections.

The typical approach to support a (much) higher number of online users is to use a connection pool inside your application - especially fo web applications. It's not unheard of that the ratio between the actual number of used (physical) database connections and the number of "online users" is in the area of 1:100 (so for 1000 users you would only need a connection pool that maintains 10 connections). Depending on the application and workload that ration might even be higher.

How exactly you enable a connection pool in your application depends on the technology you are using. Java web applications typically use that by default (through a JNDI datasource).

If your application (or technology) doesn't support a connection pool directly you need to use an external pooler like pgPool or pgBouncer.

Comment: I use pg libary from nodejs there a connection pools. And thanks for your answer! And its for an app not a website